# Does radar affect magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, radar

Does radar affect magnetism?
Let's say I have two magnets, one is suspending the other. Would radar affect the magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

Under some circumstances it is possible that radar effect a permanent magnet in a sufficient way. First of course by heating. All radiation that hits the magnet and is not deflected by 100% heats the magnet. Second by the use of modulated radiation.

Radar is a modulated radio wave with zillion of photons having the same direction of their electric and magnetic fields. These fields could periodically attract and repeal the electrons and the nucleus of the magnet. Does this lead to a demagnetization depends from the magnets material, shape, orientation in relation to the radar, power of the radar, his frequency of modulation and, and, and.

**Edit** after Unnikrishnan comment. There are continuous working and modulated radars. In both cases in a [magnetron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavity_magnetron) electrons are accelerated and by this the emit photons in microwave frequency. Some radars work in continuous mode and others with modulated radiation, [for example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZUSA) with 5,000 MHz.

> The AZUSA tracking radar was used to monitor initial phases of launch for the Saturn S-II by telemetry with transponder frequency of 5,060 MHz (receiver) and 5,000 MHz (transmitter) with 2.5 W of power. (Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZUSA))

Comment: "zillion of photons having the same direction of their electric and magnetic fields"- I have a slight confusion here. What do you actually mean by this sentence?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan please see my edit.

Comment: 2.5 W is remarkably low (but Saturn V was a big target). Cobra Dane peaks at 16,000,000 Watts (16 MW peak, 1 MW average).

Answer (score 0):

> Does radar affect magnetism?

If the electromagnetic radiation emitted by a radar is extremely powerful in the vicinity of a magnet it can heat reaching a temperature where it [loses its magnetization](http://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/What-temperatures-can-magnets-sustain).